# Initialize a Instance in php

Tags: php, initialization, instance

I see initialize an object sometimes with 
     *new calssname();* 
and other times just 
     *new classname;*  // without ()

Is there any difference btw. both?

Answer (score 3):

Both are acceptable (so long as there are no compulsory parameters to pass).

Answer (score 0):

Although both are acceptable in PHP, i tend to use the former for consistency as initializing without brackets does not work in Java and C++.